# Combining two rows where 1 column has a value and another is null

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, row

I am trying to combine two rows (duplicates) where either

1) Null in 1st Row and Value in 2nd Row (Or Vice-a-Versa)
2) Null in both the rows.

I need to combine these two rows to produce 1 row where there are either values for that column (if any present in either of the rows) or a null.

For example.

[image: issue]

needs to be converted to 
[image: Result]

I have set up [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80979) for the same data. Please let me know if you need any more information.

So far I have tried using Full Outer Join (which does not work with so many columns having nulls and stuff) and Pivot (which I am not sure is the right fit for this problem or not).

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID, A.PostEditDate, 
A.In1
, A.Out2, A.In3, A.Out4, A.Out5, A.Out6, A.Out7, A.Out8, A.Out9, A.Out10  FROM #TempTableRV A
full outer JOIN #TempTableRV B
On A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID AND A.PostEditDate = B.PostEditDate
where 
A.PostEditDate = '2007-06-19 00:00:00.000' 
AND 
A.EmployeeID = 25690 and A.In1 IS NULL AND B.In1 IS NULL
```

Comment: is their any chance that the tow rows in the same column have different value? if not just use group by.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT

EmployeeID,
MAX(PostEditDate) AS PostEditDate,
MAX(In1) AS In1,
MAX(Out2) AS Out2,
MAX(In3) AS In3,
MAX(Out4) AS Out4,
MAX(Out5) AS Out5,
MAX(Out6) AS Out6,
MAX(Out7) AS Out7,
MAX(Out8) AS Out8,
MAX(Out9) AS Out9,
MAX(Out10) AS Out10

FROM

#TempTableRV

GROUP BY
EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId,PostEditDate,
(SELECT In1 FROM TempTableRV WHERE T.EmployeeId=EmployeeId AND T.PostEditDate=PostEditDate AND In1 IS NOT NULL) AS In1, 
(SELECT Out2 FROM TempTableRV WHERE T.EmployeeId=EmployeeId AND T.PostEditDate=PostEditDate AND Out2 IS NOT NULL) AS Out2, 
(SELECT In3 FROM TempTableRV WHERE T.EmployeeId=EmployeeId AND T.PostEditDate=PostEditDate AND In3 IS NOT NULL) AS In3, 
(SELECT Out4 FROM TempTableRV WHERE T.EmployeeId=EmployeeId AND T.PostEditDate=PostEditDate AND Out4 IS NOT NULL) AS Out4,
Out5,Out6,Out7,Out8,Out9,Out10
FROM TempTableRV AS T
```

You can do this to the remaining columns (Out5,Out6,Out7,Out8,Out9,Out10) if required.

Comment: I have to be honest, it looks ugly but hey! it works!! Thank you.

Comment: Update if there are any nice and effective way.

Comment: I think there are other effective ways of doing this, but I am not too sure about them otherwise I would not have asked this question :) I will keep this question open so other people can weigh in.

Comment: But if the answer is effective just mark it. It will be a help for others since I googled for this answer and found nothing ready made. So this will be it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new temp table with the fixed/matching values, then update it to set the values that are sometimes null.