# sql merge two rows into one, same table. (update 1st with 2nd row data, then delete 2nd row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, rows

I would like to merge two rows into one and then delete the obsolete row.
Here is a small example of what I mean.

Initial data:

```
id | part A | part B
0  |  OK    |  NULL
1  | NULL   |  OK
```

merge 1 into 0 and then delete 1 resulting in the following.

```
id | part A | part B
0  |  OK    |  OK
```

What's the best way. There must be some kind of merge/combine function I'm overlooking.

Thanks in advance.

PS. Might be a duplicate of this: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822771/combining-two-rows-where-1-column-has-a-value-and-another-is-null)
But it didn't get a good answer.

Edit:
I'm using MS SQL (Server 2012)

Comment: How are the rows with ID=0 and the other with ID=1 related?

Comment: There isn't a relation. The user has two broken records which should be one record. The user must first use an educated guess and choose the two records to combine into one record, potentially overwriting some data. So what I need is a statement on how to combine two records into one (which are choosen by the user on id.)

Comment: So, the relation is that someone has handed us two specific `ID` values. Other column values should be copied from the higher `ID` row into the lower `ID` row, and then the higher `ID` row should be deleted? What should happen in both rows have non-`NULL` data in the same column (or can that situation not occur)?

Comment: As my previous comment stated: potentially overwriting some data.
Overwriting data is allowed. The user specifies two id's to combine, the 2nd into the 1st. Overwriting data will almost always occur, yet this is allowed and desired. NULL values may not be copied however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem - it may be possible to simplify it but I've taken it as a challenge to do it as a single statement.

```
declare @t table (id int not null, A varchar(20) null,
                  B varchar(19) null, C varchar(18) null)

//Sample data expanded from question
insert into @t (id,A,B,C) values
(0,'OKA',null,'Old'),
(1,null,'OKB','New')

//Input provided - @FromID is the row we'll delete
declare @FromID int
declare @ToID int

select @FromID = 1, @ToID = 0

//The actual query
;With src as (
    select @ToID as ID,A,B,C,0 as Del from @t where id = @FromID
    union all
    select @FromID,null,null,null,1
)
merge into @t t
using (select ID,A,B,C,Del from src) s
on
    t.ID = s.ID
when matched and Del = 0 then
    update set
        A = COALESCE(s.A,t.A),
        B=  COALESCE(s.B,t.B),
        C = COALESCE(s.C,t.C)
when matched then
    delete
;

//And show the final result
select * from @t
```

And the result is:

```
id          A                    B                   C
----------- -------------------- ------------------- ------------------
0           OKA                  OKB                 New
```

Which shows that `NULL`s haven't over-written non-`NULL`s and that, where both rows have data, we've taken the value from the row that we're deleting.

---

This works by constructing two rows in the `src` CTE - one row contains all of the data from the row we're going to remove except with the row we're copying data to as its `ID` column. The second row just contains the row to remove's ID value. But the rows also differ in a new column called `Del` which indicates whether this is the row that causes deletion (`1`) or an update (`0`).

Then, in the merge we end up matching both rows and using the `Del` column to decide which action to take.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and needed. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

in case of oracle use  sub-query for conditional delete.

delete from tablename where (partA|partB)=(select partA| partB from tablename)

Comment: I've editted my post.
I'm using ms sql to be specific

Comment: delete from tablename where Concat(partA,partB)=(select Concat(partA, partB) from tablename) , try this

Comment: How does this merge two records into one record, leaving one complete record?

Comment: Any explanation as to how this solution should work and what the outcome is? I don't understand because I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: there is two query, first one is before equal sign(=) known as outer query and 2nd one is after equal sign inside parenthesis() known as inner query. first of all inner query will execute and substitute return value after equal symbol,outer query is conditional delete query it will delete only those record who satisfied condition.

Comment: if this was your answer, don't forget to accept my answer.